# How to configure EnyimMemcachedCore to access Elasticache in AWS Lambda?

Tags: c#, memcached, .net-core, aws-lambda, enyim

I am trying to port a simple memcached client from .NET 4 to .Net Core on AWS Lambda.  I am struggling to configure the new EnyimMemcachedCore client because the examples (https://github.com/cnblogs/EnyimMemcachedCore) use appsettings.json to setup the config, but Lambda functions using .net core do not use appsettings.json.  I need to be able to setup the server/port/endpoint in the C# code.

Can anyone give me an example using EnyimMemcachedCore that creates the configuration manually?

The standard .net use of Enyim was trivial to fetch by key and return a value:

```
using Enyim.Caching;
using Enyim.Caching.Configuration;
using Enyim.Caching.Memcached;

...
// setup Enyim memcached client
MemcachedClient myCache;
MemcachedClientConfiguration config;
config = new MemcachedClientConfiguration(); 
config.AddServer("theIP", thePort);
config.Protocol = MemcachedProtocol.Text;

// instantiate client
myCache = new MemcachedClient(config);

// get the stored item
var result = myCache.Get(key);
```

How do I do something similar (configure the memcached client in code, not in a config file) with EnyimMemcachedCore?

Comment: You can still set the MemcacheClientConfiguration pointing to ElastiCache. `config.AddServer("something.cfg.usw1.cache.amazonaws.com", 11211);` This didn't work for you? AWS is yet to release ElastiCache Client and Cluster library for DotNet Core.

Answer (score 1):

```
// setup Enyim memcached client
var config = new MemcachedClientConfiguration();

//add each node manually if you can't get the Amazon.ElastiCacheCluster config for Core, 
//but if you can, use that instead of MemcachedClientConfiguration
config.AddServer("something.0001.usw1.cache.amazonaws.com", 11211);
config.AddServer("something.0002.usw1.cache.amazonaws.com", 11211);

config.Protocol = MemcachedProtocol.Text;

// instantiate client
var myCache = new Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient(config);
```

you can add the nodes individually until the cluster config becomes available for .NET Core (if it hasn't yet)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has been fixed as of today, 18 September 2018. I have tried the following appsettings, used the configuration endpoint of memcache which has one node

```
"enyimMemcached": {
    "Servers": [
        {
            "Address": "st-cache-01-v2.l0nmej.cfg.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com",
            "Port": 11211
        }
    ]
}
```

And the code on the `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddEnyimMemcached(Configuration);
```

It's working like charm. I haven't tried with two nodes yet. Please feel free to correct me if it doesn't work for more than one node

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

1. Install nuget Packages:

> EnyimMemcachedCore
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

2. Add dependencies:

```cs
using Enyim.Caching;
using Enyim.Caching.Configuration;
using Enyim.Caching.Memcached;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

3. Initialize

```cs
using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConsole();
});

ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MemcachedHelper>();

var configMemcachedOptions = new MemcachedClientOptions();
configMemcachedOptions.UseSslStream = true;
var config = new MemcachedClientConfiguration(loggerFactory, configMemcachedOptions);
config.AddServer(serverAddress, port);
config.Protocol = MemcachedProtocol.Text;

_memcachedClient = new MemcachedClient(loggerFactory, config);
```

More information can be found in here: https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/10/using-a-distributed-memory-cache-with-net-lambda-functions/

Just remember to turn on `configMemcachedOptions.UseSslStream = true;`